# When I upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04.6 to 22.04 Internet not working

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, internet

I have a virtual linux server used to host splunk, when i upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 all internet on the machine goes, cant ping askubuntu, google or any site, it cant fetch updates if i do apt-get update, i have tried turning the wifi card on and off e.g ifup ens but it says its running ifconfig returns ip etc, i dont have a gui on this machine and as its virtually hosted its very difficult to navigate i.e i cant scroll up so when i try access logs its making it difficult to troubleshoot is there any common fixes?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What is your host OS? What virtualization software do you use? Show the network configuration of your virtual machine in the virtualization software (not in your guest OS). In your virtual machine, do you see the real WiFi hardware or some other virtual network card?